# Installing ANTLR IDE with Aptana

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana, antlr3

I'm trying to install Antlr IDE with Aptana and I got this error log from the Update Manager. What exactly is going on?

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: ANTLR IDE- StringTemplate Tools 1.1.0.201108281759 (org.deved.antlride.feature.stringtemplate.feature.group 1.1.0.201108281759)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Runtime 3.6.0.v20100505 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0.v20100505)
    Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258)
    To: org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0.v20100505]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ANTLR IDE- StringTemplate Tools 1.1.0.201108281759 (org.deved.antlride.feature.stringtemplate.feature.group 1.1.0.201108281759)
    To: org.eclipse.dltk.core [3.0.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dynamic Languages Toolkit Core 3.0.0.v20110609-1525 (org.eclipse.dltk.core 3.0.0.v20110609-1525)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.4.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dynamic Languages Toolkit Core 3.0.1.v20110823 (org.eclipse.dltk.core 3.0.1.v20110823)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.4.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EMF Ecore 2.7.0.v20110605-0747 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.7.0.v20110605-0747)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EMF Ecore 2.7.0.v20110912-0920 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.7.0.v20110912-0920)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, ANTLR IDE is based on Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), while Aptana Studio stand-alone is shipped with Eclipse 3.6. That's probably the reason you are getting this installation issue.

You can install Aptana Studio as a plugin on top of Eclipse 3.7, and then install ANTLR IDE as well.

Checkout the http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/ (Aptana Studio tab) for the Studio's update site.